# how to add new data to firebase with flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am try to make post to fire with flutter
am using this code but is don`t work

```
 final CollectionReference _productCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cars');

  Future<void> addCarsToFireStore(ProductModel productModel) async {
    return await _productCollectionRef.doc().set(productModel.toJson());
  }

  Future addCars() async {
    return await _productCollectionRef.add({
      'name': name,
      'image': image,
      'description': description,
      'price': price,
      'country': box.read(NAME_OF_CONTRY),
      'number': number,
      'uid': box.read('uid'),
    });
  }
```

and i use this code in UI

```
CustomTextFormFild(
                    onSave: (value) {
                      value == null
                          ? Text('Valid value')
                          : value = controller.name;
                    },)
```

I do this to all content
I also have this to save the picture

```
 CustomButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          controller.getImage(ImageSource.gallery);

                          controller.image = controller.selectedImagePath.value;
                        },
                        text: 'upload image',
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      ),
```

i want to make post whith this button

```
CustomButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        controller.addCars();
                      },
                      text: 'add post',
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    ),
```

i hope some one help me

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to await:

```
CustomButton(
onPressed: () async  {
  await controller.addCars();
},
text: 'add post',
alignment: Alignment.center,
),
```